# Because I only see the last element of the for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm having a problem; I have the following program code:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://wjko5k6250.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/motorcycle"; 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   var allmot = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   console.log(allmot);
    for(var i = 0, len = allmot.Items.length; i < len; i++)
    {
      id=allmot.Items[i].id
      var url1 = "https://wjko5k6250.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/motorcycle/"+id; 
      console.log(url1);
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          console.log(myArr);
          document.getElementById("img").src = myArr.Item.image;
          document.getElementById("brd").innerHTML = myArr.Item.brand;  
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url1, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

`allmot` is as follows:

```
Items: Array (4)
0: {brand: 'Guzzi', id: '123456', image: 'moto_guzzi.jpg', date: '27/11/2021 '}
1: {brand: 'Bimota', id: '135623', image: 'bimota.jpg', date: '04/12/2021 '}
2: {brand: 'Ducati', id: '123789', image: 'b_desertx.jpg', date: ' 04/12/2021 '}
3: {brand: 'Benelli', id:' 146975 ', image:' benelli.jpg ', date: '27/11/2021'}
```

`url1` returns (according to the for loop):

```
https://wjko5k6250.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles/123456
https://wjko5k6250.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles/135623
https://wjko5k6250.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles/123789
https://wjko5k6250.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles/146975
```

and so far everything seems to be fine.

The problem is in `myArr`; I noticed that it returns the image and brand of the last element only, so the one that has id equal to 146975.

Therefore there seems to be problems with the for loop.

Can anyone kindly help me? Thank you all.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to get instead? I mean you're setting the src of `#img` and the content of `#brd` over and over again, the final result will definitely be the last set values.

Comment: For each one I want to get the image and the brand.
It does this only for the last element

Comment: But you have only a single image and that other element. `document.getElementById` finds only the first element with the passed `id` from the DOM. If you've multiple elements with the same `id`, that won't work. Notice also what pid has answered.

Comment: I answered below @pid's answer

Answer (score 2):

As first correction I'd not recycle the XHR object from the outer loop in the inner loop.

When you say `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() ...` in the inner loop, the `xmlhttp` is already in the `readystate`, obtained in the outer loop.

So, without further checking what is going on, I'd use two XHR objects (maybe like `outerXmlhttp` and `innerXmlhttp`). I'd also recreate the inner XHR for every cycle with:

```
var innerXmlhttp;
```

at the top of the outer closure.

Then, inside the cycle do:

```
innerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

This is because of variable hoisting. If you just do this:

```
var innerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

inside the cycle you may get a different behaviour. Just don't do it and write what you mean (hoist variables and assign them where you actually need it).

If all of this isn't enough ask a new, more precise question about what is going on.

This is your code with the corrections:

```js
var outerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://wjko5k6250.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/motorcycle"; 
outerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var innerXmlhttp;

  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   var allmot = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   console.log(allmot);
    for(var i = 0, len = allmot.Items.length; i < len; i++)
    {
      id=allmot.Items[i].id
      var url1 = "https://wjko5k6250.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/motorcycle/"+id; 
      console.log(url1);

      innerXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      innerXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          console.log(myArr);
          document.getElementById("img").src = myArr.Item.image;
          document.getElementById("brd").innerHTML = myArr.Item.brand;  
        }
      };
      innerXmlhttp.open("GET", url1, true);
      innerXmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
};
outerXmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
outerXmlhttp.send();
```

---

**EDIT:** @Teemu's eagle eye

As @Teemu points out in his comment, if you reassign values over and over to the same DOM objects like this:

```
document.getElementById("img").src = myArr.Item.image;
document.getElementById("brd").innerHTML = myArr.Item.brand;
```

you're clearly overwriting whatever value was there before. Instead, you should create and append those DOM objects, more like this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = myArr.Item.image;
var brd = document.createElement("p");
brd.innerText = myArr.Item.brand;
document.getElementById("motlist").append(img);
document.getElementById("motlist").append(brd);
```

Obviously, you'll need a `<div id="motlist"></div>` element or some other parent in the DOM to which to append the new elements.

For paging you may also want to clear those elements in the list... but here we're going overboard.

Comment: I answer with a single question. In fact, I understood what @Teemu means but I need to have every image and every brand of every motorcycle through the for cycle. I would need to figure out how to do this. Can you help me with a complete code please?

Comment: I only have to have two divs, one for the brand and the other for the image

Comment: The code above is sufficient to guide you in writing your own code. I will not write the code for you, or you'll not learn anything from your homework.

Comment: no I didn't mean that. Since I'm a beginner, if I already have `document.getElementById("img").src = myArr.Item.image;` how can I put `document.getElementById("motlist").append(img);` ?